# Shopware 6 Create a default entity in migration file

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

How can i store a default record using the migration file?

In symfony/doctrine there are a [method like `postUp()`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/3.5/reference/migration-classes.html#postup) which is missing in `shopware`.
So how can i do this? The shopware doc provides a tutorial [Creating data with a given ID](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/writing-data#creating-data-with-a-given-id), but i cannot **initialize the needed repository**.

So **how can i access the entityRepository** inside the migration class? Or is there another way to create a default record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The recommended way is to just create the table in the migration file and then upsert the default records in the `activate` and `update` methods of the Plugin class. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73518192/4303873) by @dneustadt**

**Please read the comments to this answer for further information.**

You can't use an EntityRepository inside a migration file. You can only use raw SQL queries by using the `$connection` variable which is passed to the `update` method.

Example:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Swag\BasicExample\Migration;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Migration\MigrationStep;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Uuid\Uuid;

class Migration1611740369ExampleDescription extends MigrationStep
{
    public function getCreationTimestamp(): int
    {
        return 1611740369;
    }

    public function update(Connection $connection): void
    {
        // create table
        $createTableSql = <<<SQL
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `swag_basic_example_general_settings` (
                `id`                INT             NOT NULL,
                `example_setting`   VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
                `created_at`        DATETIME(3)     NOT NULL,
                `updated_at`        DATETIME(3),
                PRIMARY KEY (id)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
        SQL;

        $connection->executeStatement($createTableSql);

        // insert default setting
        $insertDefaultSettingSql = <<<SQL
            INSERT INTO `swag_basic_example_general_settings`
              (`id`, `example_setting`, `created_at`)
            VALUES (:id, :example_setting, NOW())
        SQL;

        $connection->executeStatement(
            $insertDefaultSettingSql,
            [
                'id' => Uuid::randomBytes(),
                'example_setting' => 'example_value',
            ]
        );
    }

    public function updateDestructive(Connection $connection): void
    {
    }
}
```

Note: When using `Connection` instead of an entity repository you need to use `Uuid::randomBytes()` instead of `Uuid::randomHex()`. If you want to use an existing ID instead of a generated one you can use `Uuid::fromHexToBytes('0fa91ce3e96a4bc2be4bd9ce752c3425')`

Comment: Executing raw SQL is the most reasonable approach when you want to alter the database structure, e.g. add tables. However when persisting content one should always primarily use the respective repository. Otherwise it could lead to missing indexed data and other necessary processes being passed over.

Comment: @dneustadt Yes, but he asked for "How can i store a default record using the migration file?". So for creating one (or more) default records once, a raw query should be the correct approach, no? I agree that in any other case using the respective repository is the right way.

Comment: It really depends on the entity. Some entities can more safely be persisted with raw SQL than others. It depends whether they have fields that need to be indexed or computed during runtime. And there's of cause always the possible that 3rd party extensions listen to the persistence of entities through the DAL and you'd pass them over completely at that point. Yes, Shopware does persist default data on updates using migrations as well, but they have these things in mind and I would argue system default data is a little different than plugin default data.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I added a hint to the beginning of this answer.

Comment: So would the recommended way be to just create the table in the migration file and then upsert the default records in the `activate` and `update` commands of the Plugin class?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd recommend.

Comment: @rammi22 Please see the updated answer and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `Plugin` extension you can access the DI container and get any public services including the repositories:

```php
class MyPlugin extends Plugin
{
    public function activate(ActivateContext $context)
    {
        $productRepository = $this->container->get('product.repository');
    }
}
```